# Some emojis don't match my Emoji-only regex

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

I'm building a chat, and I want to increase the font size of the text when it contains only Emojis

So, we have this regex that matches all Emojis.
https://www.regextester.com/106421

I moved it in a JS function, but there are some that don't return `true` in my function (even if they match in the above Regex link).

```js
var emojiRanges = [
  '\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff]',
  ' ',
].join('|')


function isEmojiOnly(text) {
  text = text.replace(new RegExp(emojiRanges, 'g'), '')
  return text.length === 0
}


console.log(isEmojiOnly('')) // returns true
console.log(isEmojiOnly('')) // returns true
console.log(isEmojiOnly('️')) // returns false
console.log(isEmojiOnly('☘️')) // returns false
```

It works pretty well on Facebook Messenger

[image]

Any idea? =)

Comment: That is not an emoji regex. It matches a vast array of non-emoji. I think you're looking for the 9k byte emoji regex.

Comment: You seem to need 1 more char: `var emojiRanges = [
  '\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff]|\uFE0F',
  '\\s+',
].join('|')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer works but is very dirty.

Major browsers now support [unicode property escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) which allows for matching emojis based on their belonging in the `Emoji` unicode category: `\p{Emoji}` matches an emoji, `P{Emoji}` matches a non-emoji. Make sure to include [the `u` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode) at the end.

```js
const isOnlyEmojis = str => /^\p{Emoji}*$/gu.test(str);

console.log(isOnlyEmojis('')); // true
console.log(isOnlyEmojis('')); // true
console.log(isOnlyEmojis('hello ')); // false
console.log(isOnlyEmojis('hello')); // false
```

Comment: Wow.. this is coool

Answer (score 0):

This is a little larger regex, but should only match emoji or whitespace.

```js
var emojiRx = new RegExp(
'^(?:\\s+|[#*0-9]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u00a9\ufe0f?|[\u00ae\u203c\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21a9\u21aa]\ufe0f?|[\u231a\u231b]|[\u2328\u23cf]\ufe0f?|[\u23e9-\u23ec]|[\u23ed-\u23ef]\ufe0f?|\u23f0|[\u23f1\u23f2]\ufe0f?|\u23f3|[\u23f8-\u23fa\u24c2\u25aa\u25ab\u25b6\u25c0\u25fb\u25fc]\ufe0f?|[\u25fd\u25fe]|[\u2600-\u2604\u260e\u2611]\ufe0f?|[\u2614\u2615]|\u2618\ufe0f?|\u261d(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff]|\ufe0f)?|[\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262a\u262e\u262f\u2638-\u263a\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|[\u2648-\u2653]|[\u265f\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267b\u267e]\ufe0f?|\u267f|\u2692\ufe0f?|\u2693|[\u2694-\u2697\u2699\u269b\u269c\u26a0]\ufe0f?|[\u26a1\u26aa\u26ab]|[\u26b0\u26b1]\ufe0f?|[\u26bd\u26be\u26c4\u26c5]|\u26c8\ufe0f?|\u26ce|[\u26cf\u26d1\u26d3]\ufe0f?|\u26d4|\u26e9\ufe0f?|\u26ea|[\u26f0\u26f1]\ufe0f?|[\u26f2\u26f3]|\u26f4\ufe0f?|\u26f5|[\u26f7\u26f8]\ufe0f?|\u26f9(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?|\ufe0f(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\u26fa\u26fd]|\u2702\ufe0f?|\u2705|[\u2708\u2709]\ufe0f?|[\u270a\u270b](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\u270c\u270d](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff]|\ufe0f)?|\u270f\ufe0f?|[\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271d\u2721]\ufe0f?|\u2728|[\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747]\ufe0f?|[\u274c\u274e\u2753-\u2755\u2757]|[\u2763\u2764]\ufe0f?|[\u2795-\u2797]|\u27a1\ufe0f?|[\u27b0\u27bf]|[\u2934\u2935\u2b05-\u2b07]\ufe0f?|[\u2b1b\u2b1c\u2b50\u2b55]|[\u3030\u303d\u3297\u3299]\ufe0f?|\ud83c(?:[\udc04\udccf]|[\udd70\udd71\udd7e\udd7f]\ufe0f?|[\udd8e\udd91-\udd9a]|\udde6\ud83c[\udde8-\uddec\uddee\uddf1\uddf2\uddf4\uddf6-\uddfa\uddfc\uddfd\uddff]|\udde7\ud83c[\udde6\udde7\udde9-\uddef\uddf1-\uddf4\uddf6-\uddf9\uddfb\uddfc\uddfe\uddff]|\udde8\ud83c[\udde6\udde8\udde9\uddeb-\uddee\uddf0-\uddf5\uddf7\uddfa-\uddff]|\udde9\ud83c[\uddea\uddec\uddef\uddf0\uddf2\uddf4\uddff]|\uddea\ud83c[\udde6\udde8\uddea\uddec\udded\uddf7-\uddfa]|\uddeb\ud83c[\uddee-\uddf0\uddf2\uddf4\uddf7]|\uddec\ud83c[\udde6\udde7\udde9-\uddee\uddf1-\uddf3\uddf5-\uddfa\uddfc\uddfe]|\udded\ud83c[\uddf0\uddf2\uddf3\uddf7\uddf9\uddfa]|\uddee\ud83c[\udde8-\uddea\uddf1-\uddf4\uddf6-\uddf9]|\uddef\ud83c[\uddea\uddf2\uddf4\uddf5]|\uddf0\ud83c[\uddea\uddec-\uddee\uddf2\uddf3\uddf5\uddf7\uddfc\uddfe\uddff]|\uddf1\ud83c[\udde6-\udde8\uddee\uddf0\uddf7-\uddfb\uddfe]|\uddf2\ud83c[\udde6\udde8-\udded\uddf0-\uddff]|\uddf3\ud83c[\udde6\udde8\uddea-\uddec\uddee\uddf1\uddf4\uddf5\uddf7\uddfa\uddff]|\uddf4\ud83c\uddf2|\uddf5\ud83c[\udde6\uddea-\udded\uddf0-\uddf3\uddf7-\uddf9\uddfc\uddfe]|\uddf6\ud83c\udde6|\uddf7\ud83c[\uddea\uddf4\uddf8\uddfa\uddfc]|\uddf8\ud83c[\udde6-\uddea\uddec-\uddf4\uddf7-\uddf9\uddfb\uddfd-\uddff]|\uddf9\ud83c[\udde6\udde8\udde9\uddeb-\udded\uddef-\uddf4\uddf7\uddf9\uddfb\uddfc\uddff]|\uddfa\ud83c[\udde6\uddec\uddf2\uddf3\uddf8\uddfe\uddff]|\uddfb\ud83c[\udde6\udde8\uddea\uddec\uddee\uddf3\uddfa]|\uddfc\ud83c[\uddeb\uddf8]|\uddfd\ud83c\uddf0|\uddfe\ud83c[\uddea\uddf9]|\uddff\ud83c[\udde6\uddf2\uddfc]|\ude01|\ude02\ufe0f?|[\ude1a\ude2f\ude32-\ude36]|\ude37\ufe0f?|[\ude38-\ude3a\ude50\ude51\udf00-\udf20]|[\udf21\udf24-\udf2c]\ufe0f?|[\udf2d-\udf35]|\udf36\ufe0f?|[\udf37-\udf7c]|\udf7d\ufe0f?|[\udf7e-\udf84]|\udf85(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udf86-\udf93]|[\udf96\udf97\udf99-\udf9b\udf9e\udf9f]\ufe0f?|[\udfa0-\udfc1]|\udfc2(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udfc3\udfc4](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udfc5\udfc6]|\udfc7(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udfc8\udfc9]|\udfca(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udfcb\udfcc](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?|\ufe0f(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udfcd\udfce]\ufe0f?|[\udfcf-\udfd3]|[\udfd4-\udfdf]\ufe0f?|[\udfe0-\udff0]|\udff3(?:\u200d\ud83c\udf08|\ufe0f(?:\u200d\ud83c\udf08)?)?|\udff4(?:\u200d\u2620\ufe0f?|\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc62\udb40(?:\udc65\udb40\udc6e\udb40\udc67|\udc73\udb40\udc63\udb40\udc74|\udc77\udb40\udc6c\udb40\udc73)\udb40\udc7f)?|[\udff5\udff7]\ufe0f?|[\udff8-\udfff])|\ud83d(?:[\udc00-\udc14]|\udc15(?:\u200d\ud83e\uddba)?|[\udc16-\udc3e]|\udc3f\ufe0f?|\udc40|\udc41(?:\u200d\ud83d\udde8\ufe0f?|\ufe0f(?:\u200d\ud83d\udde8\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udc42\udc43](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udc44\udc45]|[\udc46-\udc50](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udc51-\udc65]|[\udc66\udc67](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udc68(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\u2764\ufe0f?\u200d\ud83d(?:\udc8b\u200d\ud83d)?\udc68|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d(?:\udc66(?:\u200d\ud83d\udc66)?|\udc67(?:\u200d\ud83d[\udc66\udc67])?|[\udc68\udc69]\u200d\ud83d(?:\udc66(?:\u200d\ud83d\udc66)?|\udc67(?:\u200d\ud83d[\udc66\udc67])?)|[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92])|\ud83e[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])|\ud83c(?:\udffb(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd]))?|\udffc(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c\udffb|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?|\udffd(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c[\udffb\udffc]|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?|\udffe(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c[\udffb-\udffd]|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?|\udfff(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c[\udffb-\udffe]|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?))?|\udc69(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\u2764\ufe0f?\u200d\ud83d(?:\udc8b\u200d\ud83d)?[\udc68\udc69]|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d(?:\udc66(?:\u200d\ud83d\udc66)?|\udc67(?:\u200d\ud83d[\udc66\udc67])?|\udc69\u200d\ud83d(?:\udc66(?:\u200d\ud83d\udc66)?|\udc67(?:\u200d\ud83d[\udc66\udc67])?)|[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92])|\ud83e[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])|\ud83c(?:\udffb(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c[\udffc-\udfff]|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?|\udffc(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d(?:\udc68\ud83c[\udffb\udffd-\udfff]|\udc69\ud83c\udffb)|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?|\udffd(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d(?:\udc68\ud83c[\udffb\udffc\udffe\udfff]|\udc69\ud83c[\udffb\udffc])|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?|\udffe(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d(?:\udc68\ud83c[\udffb-\udffd\udfff]|\udc69\ud83c[\udffb-\udffd])|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?|\udfff(?:\u200d(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udf3e\udf73\udf93\udfa4\udfa8\udfeb\udfed]|\ud83d[\udcbb\udcbc\udd27\udd2c\ude80\ude92]|\ud83e(?:\udd1d\u200d\ud83d[\udc68\udc69]\ud83c[\udffb-\udffe]|[\uddaf-\uddb3\uddbc\uddbd])))?))?|\udc6a|[\udc6b-\udc6d](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udc6e(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\udc6f(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?|\udc70(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udc71(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\udc72(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udc73(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udc74-\udc76](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udc77(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\udc78(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udc79-\udc7b]|\udc7c(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udc7d-\udc80]|[\udc81\udc82](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\udc83(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udc84|\udc85(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udc86\udc87](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udc88-\udca9]|\udcaa(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udcab-\udcfc]|\udcfd\ufe0f?|[\udcff-\udd3d]|[\udd49\udd4a]\ufe0f?|[\udd4b-\udd4e\udd50-\udd67]|[\udd6f\udd70\udd73]\ufe0f?|\udd74(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff]|\ufe0f)?|\udd75(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?|\ufe0f(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udd76-\udd79]\ufe0f?|\udd7a(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udd87\udd8a-\udd8d]\ufe0f?|\udd90(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff]|\ufe0f)?|[\udd95\udd96](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udda4|[\udda5\udda8\uddb1\uddb2\uddbc\uddc2-\uddc4\uddd1-\uddd3\udddc-\uddde\udde1\udde3\udde8\uddef\uddf3\uddfa]\ufe0f?|[\uddfb-\ude44]|[\ude45-\ude47](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\ude48-\ude4a]|\ude4b(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\ude4c(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\ude4d\ude4e](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\ude4f(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\ude80-\udea2]|\udea3(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udea4-\udeb3]|[\udeb4-\udeb6](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udeb7-\udebf]|\udec0(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udec1-\udec5]|\udecb\ufe0f?|\udecc(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udecd-\udecf]\ufe0f?|[\uded0-\uded2\uded5]|[\udee0-\udee5\udee9]\ufe0f?|[\udeeb\udeec]|[\udef0\udef3]\ufe0f?|[\udef4-\udefa\udfe0-\udfeb])|\ud83e(?:[\udd0d\udd0e]|\udd0f(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udd10-\udd17]|[\udd18-\udd1c](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udd1d|[\udd1e\udd1f](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\udd20-\udd25]|\udd26(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udd27-\udd2f]|[\udd30-\udd36](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\udd37(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udd38\udd39](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\udd3a|\udd3c(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?|[\udd3d\udd3e](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\udd3f-\udd45\udd47-\udd71\udd73-\udd76\udd7a-\udda2\udda5-\uddaa\uddae-\uddb4]|[\uddb5\uddb6](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\uddb7|[\uddb8\uddb9](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\uddba|\uddbb(?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|[\uddbc-\uddca]|[\uddcd-\uddcf](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|\uddd0|\uddd1(?:\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83e\uddd1|\ud83c(?:\udffb(?:\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83e\uddd1\ud83c\udffb)?|\udffc(?:\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83e\uddd1\ud83c[\udffb\udffc])?|\udffd(?:\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83e\uddd1\ud83c[\udffb-\udffd])?|\udffe(?:\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83e\uddd1\ud83c[\udffb-\udffe])?|\udfff(?:\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83e\uddd1\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?))?|[\uddd2-\uddd5](?:\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?|\uddd6(?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\uddd7-\udddd](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?)?|[\uddde\udddf](?:\u200d[\u2640\u2642]\ufe0f?)?|[\udde0-\uddff\ude70-\ude73\ude78-\ude7a\ude80-\ude82\ude90-\ude95]))*$');


function isEmojiOnly(text) {
  if ( emojiRx.exec( text ) )
      return true;
  return false;
}


console.log(isEmojiOnly('')) // returns true
console.log(isEmojiOnly('')) // returns true
console.log(isEmojiOnly('️')) // returns true
console.log(isEmojiOnly('☘️')) // returns true
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought it was about ranges. But nice ;) Thank you